# Are there cases where the state update logic itself does not execute in React?

Tags: reactjs

Implementing multiple modals where a modal calls a modal in React
I'm facing a challenge and posting a question

For the source, I think it is better to leave the github address rather than copying it, so please understand that I replace it with a github link.

https://github.com/graylobo/modalTest

The logic is as follows.

1. define a base modal to be used globally (BaseModal)
2. manage BaseModal's on/off with recoil
3. useModalStack to open the custom modal (TestModal1,2)
4. custom modal can call other custom modals, and modal callers can share the state of the caller. This means that when SomeComponent calls TestModal1, and TestModal1 calls TestModal2, it can get the status of TestModal2 from TestModal1, and get the status of TestModal1 from SomeComponent.

The above functions work without any problems,

If TestModal1 has its own local state (inputData) and currentModal.handleConfirm?.(inputData) is called when the Confirm button is clicked, and the callback logic specified in SomeComponent's handleConfirm is executed, the status update of receivedData through setReceivedData is updated normally with the inputData passed by TestModal1.

Also, as with the process in which SomeComponent called TestModal1,
TestModal1 calls TestModal2, and
TestModal2 has its own local state (inputData) and clicks the OK button to call the
currentModal.handleConfirm?.(inputData), the callback logic specified in TestModal1's handleConfirm will be executed and the
It works fine until it receives the inputData passed by TestModal2.
The problem here is that the state of receivedData should be updated to the inputData passed by TestModal2 through setReceivedData of TestModal1, but when debugging, setReceivedData itself is not executed at all.

This is the first time I've encountered that the callback function that I pass to the set function of useState doesn't execute itself while developing react, and I don't have any reference, so if anyone has encountered the same problem or knows the solution, I would be very grateful for your advice.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)